# How to go directly to a HTML-form authenticator registration page from a MFA

Tags: curity

I am wondering how I can go directly to a HTML-form authenticator registration page from a Conditional Multi-Factor action (MFA).

In a switch action I want to go to a HTML form authenticator create account page.
The setup right to the HTML form is by using a conditional Multi-Factor action (MFA).
Switch -> MFA -> HTML-form

But can't figure out how to redirect directly to the create account (registration) page in HTML form. So that I don't first see the sign in HTML form page and have to click the Create account link

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to go directly to the registration page, but you have some options.

You could use the `Attribute Prompt` action to collect the data you want to register. Then you add a `Autocreate Account` action that will register the account. If you configure an `Account Manager` that has the option `Set Password after activation` enabled, the user will get an email with a  link that prompts the user to set the password for the account.
The flow would be `Attribute Prompt -> Create Account -> Authenticated`, and the password will be set out of band.

Second option would be to create a custom action using the SDK that collects the data you need and creates an account using a `Credential Manager` and an `Account Manager`. Using the SDK is not available in the community license.